# reading and deleting lines in python

Tags: python

I am trying to read all the lines in a specific file, and it prints the number of the line as an index.

What I am trying to do is to delete the line by inputting the number of the line by the user.
As far as it is now, it prints all the lines with the number of that line, but when I enter the number of the line to be deleted, it's not deleted.

This is the code of the delete function:

```
def deleteorders ():

    index = 0
    fh = open ('orders.txt', 'r')
    lines = fh.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        lines = fh.readlines()
        index = index+1
        print (str(index) + ' ' + line)


    try:
        indexinp = int(input('Enter the number of the order to be deleted, or "B" to go back: '))

        if indexinp == 'B':
            return
        else:
            del line[indexinp]
            print (line)

            fh = open ('orders.txt', 'w')
            fh.writelines(line)
            fh.close()

    except:
        print ('The entered number is not in the range')
        return
```

Comment: When you execute this line `lines = fh.readlines()` the variable `lines` becomes a Python list of the lines in the file, numbered (automatically) from 0 through the number of lines in the file minus one. To delete a line, `index` (say), from this list it's sufficient to write `del lines[index]`. **But be careful**. Most of us make this mistake sooner or later. All of the lines beyond the one you deleted will be renumbered.

Comment: Why is there `lines = fh.readlines()` in the `for` loop?

Comment: @Matthias It's incorrect, yea.

Comment: Thanks, I deleted the one in the for loop, and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

This should work (you'll need to add the error handling back in):

```
lines = enumerate(open('orders.txt'))
for i, line in lines:
    print i, line
i = int(input(">"))
open('orders.txt', 'w').write(''.join((v for k, v in lines if k != i)))
```